# Can't reorder Structure pages

Tags: add-on, structure, pages

I'm having issues with Structure module... When I try to make a child page, it does this...

[image]

But if I remove it as a child page, and refresh it puts the styling back but the page is in totally the wrong place?!

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was run Structure Debugging on it. I didn't know this existed but it fixed my problem.

> http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/debug_mode_for_page_data/

Simply change the debug option to **TRUE** in the MCP file, run the debugging. This removed my entries from Structure, but they were still in **Publish > Edit**, so I just added a **Structure URL Title** to each entry.

Boom, done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working for hours trying to fix this problem and this did it!

Answer (score 1):

How many pages/entries are structure managed in total? Looks like you might be suffering from the structure reorder bug (which is not a structure bug).

Take a look at http://madebyhippo.com/blog/view/structure_reorder_bug which will give you more details on it.

Alternatively, if you file a support bug with Travis at Structure, quoting this SE post - he can redirect the ticket through to me where I can have a look for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. I have come across a similar problem before but this is because Structure had left a row in the exp_structure table that wasn't being used anymore. I think this was back in EE1 days. But I checked this and they are all fine.

I'll give these suggestions a go and I'm just awaiting a reply from Travis.